# HTML To Image To Base64

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, base64, html2canvas

I am struggling with this situation, where I have some HTML markup in a JavaScript variable.

What I want is, to convert the value of that variable into an image and get the base64 value:

```
var print_markup = '';
print_markup += '<h2 style="text-align:center">' + $scope.config.business_name + '</h2>';
print_markup += '<p style="text-align:center">' + $scope.config.business_address + '</p>';
```

I tried this [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) but it needs a dom element as its argument not an HTML string, or I am not using it right.

```
html2canvas(print_markup, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
        var base64String = dataURL.split(',')[1];

   }
})
```

But I get this:

> html2canvas.js:592 Uncaught (in promise) Proxy must be used when rendering url

Comment: htm2canvas needs `ownerDocument.defaultView`, so your elements must actually be part of the current DOM.

Comment: Thanks @Kaiido I appended the element to they body and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the link : [here](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image#usage)

```
var node = document.getElementById('my-node');

domtoimage.toPng(node)
    .then (function (dataUrl) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = dataUrl;
        document.appendChild(img);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
    });
```

Comment: without support for IE.

Answer (score 0):

As @Kaiido suggested, the `html2canvas`'s first argument is an **element** that is appended to the original document,
See this [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) for more informations